# Spock returning incorrect/default value for a getEstimatedNumIterations() call

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

On the `IterationInfo`class there exists a method called `getEstimatedNumIterations()` which, based on its javadoc, will return the total number of iterations for the ongoing execution of the owning feature. In older versions of Spock (2.0-groovy-3), this method worked as expected:

(simple, slightly absurd PoC):

```
def "Iteration test - #x"() {
  given: "a dumb way to illustrate the problem"
  println "Estimate: " + this.getSpecificationContext().getCurrentIteration().getEstimatedNumberOfIterations()

  expect:
  true

  where:
  x << [1, 2, 3]

}
```

prints `Est: 3` (x3)

However, with the latest stable release (2.3-groovy-4) that same spec produces the following:
`Est: -1` (x3)

I can see there was a decent amount of framework improvements from 2.0 -> 2.3, especially involving iteration construction. Is there any other way to get the estimated number of iterations for a feature? I am primarily using this in a few custom annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regression in the Spock Framework, I've created an [issue](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/1573).

Comment: Appreciate it. Didn't want to open an issue without checking here first, thanks.

Comment: Could you illuminate your use-case a bit more.